# Compiling a subset of Boost Libraries for Android NDK

Tags: c++, boost, android-ndk, boost-spirit

I needed one of boost libraries for my Android app so I managed to compile most of them. But when I am trying to compile filesystem component, I get following error message.

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/v2/src/v2_operations.o
libs\filesystem\v2\src\v2_operations.cpp:62:30: 
     error: sys/statvfs.h: No such file or directory
```

I understand that this is because Android NDK's gcc does not have the part related to `statvfs.h`.

What I am wondering, is if filesystem component is necessary for boost-spirit? Of course, if you know how to resolve that error, that would be perfect.

Comment: Have you tried boost-copy (`bcp`)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I just googled it and it's promising. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: The manual says that Boost-Spirit is header only: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/structure/include.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solving your compilation error

I haven't tried this with Boost Filesystem but it will probably work:

```
#ifndef ANDROID
  #include <sys/statvfs.h>
#else
  #include <sys/vfs.h>
  #define statvfs statfs
#endif
```

#### If Boost Spirit needs Boost Filesystem

According to [boost manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/structure/include.html) it is a header-only module. :)

#### Why doesn’t android have statvfs?

According to its [manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/statfs.2.html), statvfs is for POSIX, but Linux (and Android is based on Linux) disobeys it. Following quotes applies:

> Some systems only have `<sys/vfs.h>`, other systems also have `<sys/statfs.h>`, where the former includes the latter.  So it seems including the former is the best choice.

> Solaris, Irix and POSIX have a system call statvfs(2) that returns a struct statvfs (defined in `<sys/statvfs.h>`) containing an unsigned long f_fsid. Linux, SunOS, HP-UX, 4.4BSD have a system call statfs() that returns a struct statfs (defined in `<sys/vfs.h>`) containing a fsid_t f_fsid, where fsid_t is defined as struct { int val[2](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/statfs.2.html); }.  The same holds for FreeBSD, except that it uses the include file `<sys/mount.h>`.